# Having trouble with the data from Firestore coming back undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I get back data from the console.log results but the useState hook setDocuments is returns undefined in the following Code:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"
import { projectFirestore } from "../firebase/config"

export const useCollection = (collection, _query, _orderBy) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  // if we don't use a ref --> infinite loop in useEffect
  // _query is an array and is "different" on every function call
  const query = useRef(_query).current
  const orderBy = useRef(_orderBy).current

  useEffect(() => {
    let ref = projectFirestore.collection(collection)

    if (query) {
      ref = ref.where(...query)
    }
    if (orderBy) {
      ref = ref.orderBy(...orderBy)
    }

    const unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      let results = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc)
        results.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
      });
      console.log(results)
      // update state
      setDocuments(results)
      
      setError(null)
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
      setError('could not fetch the data')
    })

    // unsubscribe on unmount
    return () => unsubscribe()

  }, [collection, query, orderBy])

  return { documents, error}
}
```

The code above is imported into a page as a useCollection hook to call data from firestore 8.

Answer (score 0):

> You just have to remove "doc" from snapshot.doc.forEach and you can get your data by forEach function

```
const unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  ....
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc)
    results.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
  });
  ...
}, error => {
  ...
})
```